# Need to find sum of data consumed for each mobile user

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which contains sample data mentioned below
Explanation about data - 
1. Data Contains Date , IMEI number of mobile , SIM NO ( which is sent only only device restarted and sent as null else ) and Data in Percentage ( remaining data in percentage) ( can be null if device data was turned off during that time).
[image]

What I want to achieve with this table is find amount of data consumed between each data recharge ( you can observe the recharge by seeing 100 in column ). So for example first recharge was done on 3/4/20 and second recharge was done on 3/12/20 and total data consume between this recharge is 100 - 73 = 27 ( subtracting the first on recharge and last of that recharge ). This is percent number , I can multiply this by 1024 ( assuming data is in MB). 
I have tried few queries but could not come up with an efficient query. Please help me.

Comment: BigQuery or MySQL?

Comment: BigQuery Standard SQL

Answer (score 1):

Use a cumulative sum to define the regions and then aggregation.  I am going to assume BigQuery:

```
select imei, min(date) as recharge_date, max(date) as last,
       max(data_usage) - min(data_usage) as data_consumed
from (select t.*,
             countif(data_usage = 100) over (partition by imei order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by imei, grp;
```

Comment: One more question adding to this , lets assume if the recharge is not marked with 100 but a number which will be greater than just the last number. Do you have any recommendation for that

Comment: @ajaymishra . . . Then you would have a *different* question.  This one clearly specifies that the recharge is 100 and this answers it.  If you have a different problem, ask a new question.